# Keep posting of same answers when one was already posted

Tags: discussion, support

I reached to a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094252/uialertview-delegate-is-not-working-well-in-swift, where it'd already got 4 of answers (questioner already commented on one of the answers, that, "thanks for the help and [blah blah]...")

I noticed that, there's most of the answer is same and posted in 2-3 minutes of the gap. When a user giving an answer to particular questions, if he'll see an answer (which is same to his answer) then still he should give the answer or not?

What should I do in this situation?

Should I raise a flag to moderators of duplication (of same answer). Would they notice the situation (that, one of the answers (which looks similar to others) which posted first should only acceptable here. And all the other answers should be deleted or removed?

Should I ask other answers users that why they are duplicating the answers which are same and already posted?

There's many questions on Stack Overflow which has the same situation. Would it be never change or update?